# Ada unconstrained type

Tags: ada

Hello Im new to ada and I am trying to create some kind of unconstrained array and I can't figure out how to do it in ada.

```
package data_puzzle is
    type rotation is private;
    type map(x_l,y_l,z_l : Natural) is private;
    type valid_rotations is private;
private
    type rotation is array(1..3) of Natural; 
    type map(x_l,y_l,z_l : Natural) is record
        struct : Structure(x_l,y_l,z_l);
        rot : rotation;
    end record;

    type valid_rotations is array(1..24) of map; --how can I make this row work?
end data_puzzle;
```

Structure looks like this

```
type structure(x_l,y_l,z_l : Natural) is record
    structure : xyz(1..x_l,1..y_l,1..z_l);
    X : Natural := x_l;
    Y : Natural := y_l;
    Z : Natural := z_l;
end record;
```

Basically I have a map with rotations and data. Then I want to store all the different rotations in a list of size 24. The only solution I have right now is to initiate
type valid_rotations is array(1..24) of map(x,y,z) then it works. But I do not want to initiate it like that since I do not know what the size will be at that moment.

Cheers!

Comment: It's confusing that `type structure` has a component named `structure`! Also, I wonder why `type structure` has components `X`, `Y`, `Z` initialised to the corresponding discriminant's value when you could just access the discriminant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that the type `map` can be of varying size -- the compiler cannot therefore simply set aside the proper amount of memory w/o further information -- so the solution is to create some sort of indirection which *can* be the element of an array: we have this type since Ada 83 **but** with Ada 2005 and on we can further constrain access types from being null.

```Ada
-- I don't know what this is supposed to be; I'm assuming an array.
type xyz is Array(Positive Range <>, Positive Range <>, Positive Range <>)
  of Integer;

type structure(x_l,y_l,z_l : Natural) is record
structure : xyz(1..x_l,1..y_l,1..z_l);  
X : Natural := x_l;
Y : Natural := y_l;
Z : Natural := z_l;
end record;

package data_puzzle is
type rotation is private;
type map(x_l,y_l,z_l : Natural) is private;
type valid_rotations is private;

type map_handle is private;
private
type rotation is array(1..3) of Natural; 
type map(x_l,y_l,z_l : Natural) is record
    struct : Structure(x_l,y_l,z_l);
    rot : rotation;
end record;

-- Because the size of the record "map" can change
-- depending on its discriminants, we cannot simply
-- make some array -- we can however have an array 
-- of accesses (since we know their sizes at compile)
-- and constrain these access-types to be non-null.
type valid_rotations is array(1..24) of map_handle;

-- Here it is: an access which cannot be null.
type map_handle is Not Null Access Map;

end data_puzzle;
```

Also, I'd delete the _1 from the discriminants (X,Y,Z) look fine to me.

Comment: man it compiles now :)! And thanks for the description. Big <3!

Comment: The trouble with user-visible access types is that the user gets to do the allocation, and to remember to deallocate when done (unless they don't care about memory leaks). It may be safer to use [Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-10.html). Also, as written, the user can't actually create an instance of `data_puzzle.valid_rotations` because they can't see how to initialise it (with 24 not-null accesses to already allocated maps). I wouldn't use `not null` here; it's in the private part, at least the user can't get it wrong!

Comment: Indefinite_Vectors is a good solution, and very applicable, but if I had suggested it off the bat it wouldn't be addressing the `why` of the problem.